# Validador laravel confirmación de contraseña e idioma

Tags: laravel

Buen día, estoy trabajando con laravel 8, necesito que los mensajes de validación sean en español, lo coloqué así porque lo ví en un ejemplo, también quisiera saber si la parte de confirmacion de contraseña en el validador está bien (también lo vi en otro ejemplo) y si funciona me imagino que tengo que remover la ultima condición que coloqué donde manualmente pregunto si la contraseña y la confirmación son iguales.

Gracias.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
         $Validator = $request->validate([
                'dpi' => 'required|unique:users|max:13|min:13',
                'email' => 'required|email|unique:users|max:50',
                'password' => 'required|min:4',
                'name' => 'required',
                'nombre' => 'required',
                'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:4|same:password'
            ],[
                'dpi' => 'El DPI es Obligatorio',
                'email' => 'El Email es Obligatorio',
                'password' => 'La contraseña es Obligatorio',
                'name' => 'El Usuario es Obligatorio',
                'nombre' => 'El Nombre es Obligatorio',
                'password_confirmation' => 'Las Contraseñas no coinciden',
            ]);

      $validator->validate();

        if ($request->hasFile('imagen')){
            $file = $request->file('imagen');
            $nom_imagen = time();
            $file->move(public_path().'/imagenes/',$nom_imagen);
        }

        $cobrador = new User;
        $cobrador->id_empresa = $request->input('id_empresa');
        $cobrador->dpi = $request->dpi;
        $cobrador->name = $request->name;
        $cobrador->telefono = $request->telefono;
        $cobrador->direccion = strtoupper($request->direccion);
        $cobrador->sueldo = $request->input('sueldo');
        $cobrador->foto = $nom_imagen;
        $cobrador->nombre = strtoupper($request->nombre);
        $cobrador->email = $request->email;
        // $cobrador->password = Hash::make($request['password']);

        if ($request->input('password') === $request->input('password_confirmation')) {
          $cobrador->password = Hash::make($request['password']);
          $cobrador->save();

          /* Crear usuario con su respectivo Rol */
          $modelrol = new Model_has_Roles;
          $modelrol->role_id = $request->id_rol;
          $modelrol->model_type = 'App/User';
          $nuevo_id = User::max('id');
          $modelrol->model_id = $nuevo_id;

          $modelrol->save();

          return redirect()->action('CobradorController@index');
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($Validator)->withInput($request->all());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Los mensajes de error personalizados deben estar en el formato `[atributo].[regla]`, por lo que en tu array te falta adjuntar la regla:

```
$request->validate([
            ...
  ], [
      'dpi.required' => 'El DPI es Obligatorio',
      'email.required' => 'El Email es Obligatorio',
      'password.required' => 'La contraseña es Obligatorio',
      'name.required' => 'El Usuario es Obligatorio',
      'nombre.required' => 'El Nombre es Obligatorio',
      'password_confirmation.same' => 'Las Contraseñas no coinciden',
  ]);
```

Comment: fijate que me aparecen siempre en inglés y al momento de verificar las contraseñas no me aparece que no coinciden